# VirtualBox wont allow choose "dynamically allocated" hard disk file on creation dialog

Tags: virtualbox, disk-space-utilization

I need to create a "dynamically allocated" hard disk file on virtual box but on  creation dialog there is no option to it, there is only "Pre-allocated Full size" and "Split into 2GB parts" options on dialog as image below:
[VirtualBox disk creation dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gScfC.png)

Comment: @Robert Longson do you mean if i want "dynamically allocated" hard disk i should just uncheck the all checkboxes on this dialog ??

Answer (score 0):

That's what you have selected i.e. if you don't check the "Pre-allocated Full size" checkbox you'll get a disk that grows.